# custom smart pointer class template

Tags: c++, pointers, c++98

Kindly provide your review comments:

```
//SmartPtr.h
class RefCount {
public:
    void AddRef() {
        ++(this->_count);
    }
    int Release() {
        return --(this->_count);
    }
private:
    int _count;
};

template <class T>
class SmartPtr {

public:

    // constructor
    SmartPtr();
    SmartPtr(T* iObject);

    // copy constructor
    SmartPtr(const SmartPtr<T>& iSPtr);

    // destructor
    ~SmartPtr();

    // operators
    SmartPtr<T>& operator=(const SmartPtr<T>& iSPtr);
    T& operator*();
    T* operator->();

private:
    T* _ptr;
    RefCount* _refCount;

    void _release();
    void _copySmartPtr(const SmartPtr<T>& iSPtr);
};

//SmartPtr.cpp
#include "SmartPtr.h"

// constructor
template <class T>
SmartPtr<T>::SmartPtr():
    _refCount(nullptr),
    _ptr(nullptr)
{
}

template <class T>
SmartPtr<T>::SmartPtr(T* iObject):
    _refCount(new RefCount()),
    _ptr(iObject)
{   
    this->_refCount->AddRef();
}

// copy constructor
template <class T>
SmartPtr<T>::SmartPtr(const SmartPtr<T>& iSPtr) 
{
    this->_copySmartPtr(iSPtr);
}

// destructor
template <class T>
SmartPtr<T>::~SmartPtr() {
    this->_release();
}

// operators
template <class T>
SmartPtr<T>& SmartPtr<T>::operator=(const SmartPtr<T>& iSPtr) {
    if (iSPtr._ptr && (this != &iSPtr)) {
        this->_release();
        this->_copySmartPtr(iSPtr);
    }
    return *this;
}

template <class T>
T& SmartPtr<T>::operator*() {
    return *(this->_ptr);
}

template <class T>
T* SmartPtr<T>::operator->() {
    return this->_ptr;
}

template <class T>
void SmartPtr<T>::_release() {
    if (this->_refCount && this->_refCount->Release() == 0) {
        delete this->_ptr;
        delete this->_refCount;
    }
}

template <class T>
void SmartPtr<T>::_copySmartPtr(const SmartPtr<T>& iSPtr) {
    this->_ptr = iSPtr._ptr;
    this->_refCount = iSPtr._refCount;
    this->_refCount->AddRef();
}
```

Comment: What C++ version did you use? Is there a reason you wrote this instead of using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: You define templated class methods in a separate compilation unit without even specializing it in the header. This won't work (unless you `#include` the .cpp in each file `SmartPtr` is used in.)

Comment: I could use std::unique_ptr or std::shared_ptr, but the goal is to show a group of students how smart pointer can be implemented in c++98.

Comment: @bipll I have a separate SmartPtrComposite.cpp, where I've included the SmartPtr.cpp as below. The code is working. `#include "Composite.h"` `#include "SmartPtr.cpp"` `template class SmartPtr<Composite>;`

Comment: "the goal is to show a group of students how smart pointer can be implemented in c++98". WHY?!?!?!?!?!?! Sorry if this is too chatty, but ugh...

Comment: C++98 is still being taught? Both unique and shared have been added in C++11, a specification that came out 7 years ago and [is supported](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#cpp11) by just about any compiler I know.

Comment: Thanks Mast, Snowhawk. I appreciate your comments. I was just trying to get my hands on how to implement SmartPtr without using the shared_ptr/unique_ptr. I agree with you that it is better to use the c++11 features.

Comment: @Amit: Reimplementing standard library smart pointers is one thing (and a fine goal on its own), but is it necessary to go back to C++98 to do so? C++11 is widely available, and if it isn't, lack of smart pointers likely isn't the biggest issue. (Just my impression, YMMV)

Comment: This doesn’t merit its own answer but here’s a mini-review: *“`SmartPtr`” is a bad name*. It doesn’t tell the user what it actually does. Choose a name that’s descriptive, such as `SharedPtr` or `RefCountedPtr`.

Comment: C++98 is still widely used in legacy codebases so I don't understand the outrage displayed in the comments.

Comment: @yuri: The "outrage" is about teaching 20 year old standards to students by default. Yes, C++98 is still used in some places, but how many of those students will end up in one of those places, and in how many of those places will it still be used once those students are actually finished with their studium and looking for jobs? It's like teaching how to ride a carriage, because there are still places that use carriages instead of cars.

Comment: @hoffmale I understood that this is an example for learning purposes and todays standards will be covered later in the lecture. Makes sense to me. Off-topic but I assume 'studium' to be 'college education' in some language other than english?

Comment: @yuri: Whoops, yes (I accidentally slipped some German in there). It's university (or college) level education. For perspective, I'm currently a CS student myself, and I'd like to be rather up-to-date on the technology I studied once I've finished. Also, I guess it depends on the actual course ("history of C++" vs. "C++ introduction" makes a big difference), but sticking to one version seems to be easier for the latter option than mixing versions and confusing students, so it's likely that some might deduce that only C++98 will be taught.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### The Big Issue

One of the biggest things about smart pointers is that they guarantee deletion of the pointer. **EVEN** when exceptions happen. My main problem here is that your constructor may leak the pointer if it fails to initialize correctly.

```
template <class T>
SmartPtr<T>::SmartPtr(T* iObject):
    _refCount(new RefCount()),       // This can throw.
    _ptr(iObject)
{   
    this->_refCount->AddRef();
}
```

If the creation of the `_refCount` object fails you will leak the pointer. You need to guarantee that the pointer does not leak:

```
SmartPtr<T>::SmartPtr(T* iObject)
try                               // Add a try block
    :_refCount(new RefCount())
    ,_ptr(iObject)
{   
    this->_refCount->AddRef();
}
catch(...)
{
    delete iObject;    // If there is an exception make sure the object is deleted.
    throw;             // Then re-throw the exception.
}
```

### Minor Missing Functions

The main missing things I see are:

```
 T*  get();            // Sometimes its nice to just get the pointer.
 operator bool();      // Nice when you want to simply check the smart
                       // pointer has something in a boolean context.

 SmartPtr<Stuff>  data = getSmartPointer();
 if (data) {
     data->doWork();   // Need to check there is a pointer in the
 }                     // object before calling doWork().
```

### Constructor Problems

#### Explicit

Your one parameter constructor should be `explicit`. Think of this situation.

```
 void doStuff(SmartPtr<Stuff> work)
 {
      if (work) {
          work->doWork();
      }
 }
```

Looks simple enough. When you call the function you get another reference counted version of the pointer and thus it is simple and safe to use.

But what happens when I do this:

```
int main()
{
    Stuff*  work = new Stuff;
    doStuff(work);
    work->moreActions();
    delete work;
}
```

This code compiles. But the call to `doStuff()` results in delete being called on the `work` object. Even though you though it was safe to call (as you are making a copy of smart pointer).

The trouble is that the compiler has converted the Stuff* to a SmartPtr which is deleted in this scope.

#### What About nullptr

Your object does not accept a nullptr!

```
 SmartPtr<Stuff>  value = nullptr;  // fails to compile.
```

It does not look like a major problem. But when you start using templatized code where things are initialized and your type can be swapped in then it becomes an issue as your type can not be used.

#### What About Derived Types.

On of the major things about C++ is derived types with more functionality.

```
Derived*    x = new Derived;
Base*       y = x;
```

The same should work with smart pointers.

```
SmartPtr<Derived>  x = new Derived;
SmartPtr<Base>     y = x;           // fails to compile.
```

This will be a common in most C++ code (not exactly like this). But this functionality is really needed.

### Make Shared

One of the things the standard builders found was that each shared pointer required the allocation of **TWO** objects. One for the thing and one for the counter.

They remedied this by introducing `std::make_shared<T>()`. This does one allocation that allocates the object and the counter inside the same space thus reducing the overall overhead of the object.

### Further Reading

I cover a lot of these details and more in some articles I wrote:

[Series](http://lokiastari.com/series/)
[Smart-Pointer - Unique Pointer](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2014/12/30/c-plus-plus-by-example-smart-pointer/index.html)
[Smart-Pointer - Shared Pointer](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2015/01/15/c-plus-plus-by-example-smart-pointer-part-ii/index.html)
[Smart-Pointer - Constructors](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2015/01/23/c-plus-plus-by-example-smart-pointer-part-iii/index.html)

Comment: `nullptr` didn't exist in C++98. `operator bool()` should use [the old safe-bool idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool).

Comment: @Snowhawk Must admit I missed the C++98 mark. But that version is over 2 decades old.

Comment: Won't the blatant `delete iObject` possible try to delete a random memory address? If the constructor throws, the member is never initialised. Calling delete on an uninitialized pointer is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @rubenvb The `iObject` is passed by the caller. The contract with the caller is that the class **WILL** call delete on this object (even if the constructor throws). Otherwise you are left in a position where the smart pointer may leak.

Answer (score 7):

- As @bipll mentioned, `template`s must be fully available everywhere they are used. Maybe move the implementation to the header, or at least add a note that the .cpp file is intended to be included instead of the header, as this is unusual.
- Some operators (`*`, `->`) need `const` overloads (or need to be made `const`), as otherwise the contained pointer isn't be accessed from a `const` context, e.g. a `const SmartPtr<T>&`.
- Please provide an easier access to the underlying pointer than `smart_ptr.operator->()`. There are functions that only accept raw pointers, for which this way of accessing `SmartPtr<T>::_ptr` gets cumbersome.
- This implementation seems similar to `std::shared_ptr` in the sense that the `SmartPtr` is intended to be shared. However, if this "being shared" involves multiple threads, then accesses to `RefCount::_count` need to be synchronized. (Otherwise you get race conditions.)

  > Sadly, C++98 doesn't offer any help for this in the standard library (as the notion of threads only got formally introduced to C++11), so you have to rely on some external library and/or platform dependent operations.
- `nullptr` only got introduced in C++11, so a C++98 compiler shouldn't be able to compile this.

Comment: It’s not “just” unusual, it flat out *breaks* some build systems. Don’t do it.

Answer (score 7):

- There's no need to use `this->` to access any of the members of this class.  Simply refer to them in the natural way:

  ```
            return --_count;
   // not:  return --(this->_count);
  ```
- The `RefCount` class doesn't need to be visible outside of the pointer implementation, so it can be a private class within `SmartPtr`.
- The code has severe problems with concurrency - however, that's hard to deal with portably, before the current memory model and introduction of `std::atomic` types.

Answer (score 5):

## Consider the null case a bit more

If the smart pointer hasn't been assigned, then you have a null pointer by default. That seems fine, but if I call `*sptr` on an instance, I will get a null reference, which is UB.

This code, then, relies on the caller never calling `operator*` when the smart pointer is in this (evidently acceptable) state. To check that, the caller will have to write something like:

```
if(sptr())
   doThingWithReference(*sptr);
```

I would be inclined to make 2 changes, then: throw if the dereference operator is called when the pointer is null (exceptions are better than UB), and also to define a bool operator:

```
explicit operator bool() const {
  return _ptr == nullptr;
}
```

You mention C++98 in a comment; this `explicit` version [is only C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit) (even if you swapped nullptr for 0), prior to that you had to do [interesting things](https://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html) to prevent a bool operator making way for int casting and so on.

## Assignment to a null smart pointer will add references to nothing

Consider `SmartPtr<A> sptr_a = sptr_null`: you Release a reference in the sptr_a refcount, then assign the pointer to that in `sptr_null` (which is a null pointer), and then add 1 to the mutually held nothing.

If you then assign this again to a different smart pointer `sptr_a = sptr_b`, then the assignment operator will refuse to _release the old pointer (pointing to nothing), and refuse to copy in the new one, too. If you have received a SmartPtr as a return value and assigned it to such a pointer like this:

```
SmartPtr<A> sptr_a = sptr_null;
sptr_a = GetJewel();
```

Then `sptr_a` will still have a null pointer and the jewel will be thrown away.

## Initialise your reference count

At present, there is nothing to initialise the reference count itself to zero except some good luck. The compiler should have warned you about that.

Comment: I agree with section #1 and #3 (though value initialization takes care of that since C++03), but section #2 seems weird: Why do we need to track the number of refences to "nothing"? Wouldn't it be easier to simply add a check `if(_refCount) _refCount->AddRef();` instead of creating a special case `sptr_null` value?

Comment: @hoffmale: Sorry if that bit is unclear, it's not meant to be a special case, it's just meant to be an instance of the class which is pointing to null, and I'm illustrating a case where the bug shows itself.